# Change state when click the button in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm new to react native and want to make one function change state for the clicked button only not others that have the same function
as I explained in the title here is an example code
please any help & I know it might be a selly question but any answer will help
thanks a lot

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      opened: true,
    }
 }


 componentHideAndShow = () =>{
   this.setState(previousState => ({opened: !previousState.opened}))
 }

  render() {
      return (
            {
              this.state.opened ? <Text> hello</Text> : <Text> hello sdfsdfsdf</Text> 
            }
            <Text onPress={this.componentHideAndShow}>test</Text>
            {
              this.state.opened ? <Text> hello</Text> : <Text> hello sdfsdfsdf</Text> 
            }
            <Text onPress={this.componentHideAndShow}>test</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      opened: [true, true]
    };
  }

  componentHideAndShow = index => {
    const opened = this.state.opened;
    opened[index] = !opened[index];
    this.setState({ opened: opened });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.opened[0] ? (
          <Text> hello</Text>
        ) : (
          <Text> hello sdfsdfsdf</Text>
        )}
        <Button onPress={() => this.componentHideAndShow(0)}>test</Button>
        {this.state.opened[1] ? (
          <Text> hello</Text>
        ) : (
          <Text> hello sdfsdfsdf</Text>
        )}
        <Button onPress={() => this.componentHideAndShow(1)}>test</Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: you can do like this if you don't know the number of items:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

const myArrayOfStrings = ['hello1', 'hello2', 'hello3', 'hello4', 'hello5'];

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      opened: undefined
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let opened = [];
    myArrayOfStrings.map(item => {
      opened.push(true);
    });
    this.setState({ opened: opened });
  }

  componentHideAndShow = index => {
    const opened = this.state.opened;
    opened[index] = !opened[index];
    this.setState({ opened: opened });
  };

  render() {
    const output = myArrayOfStrings.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>
            {this.state.opened[index]
              ? `${item} is opened`
              : `${item} is opened`}
          </Text>
          <Button onPress={() => this.componentHideAndShow(0)}>test</Button>
        </View>
      );
    });

    return <View>{output}</View>;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for response , it works perfectly for this case , but if i have unknown number of buttons and its content came from api for example how can i handle this case , actually this is my case that i working on , thanks again

Comment: I edited the answer, it will work with an unknown number of buttons. Don't forget to accept that answer if it works.

Comment: unfortunately didn't work , if you have any ideas tell me , thanks a lot

Comment: Well, normally the array will not be hardcoded as it is here. It will come from a database, from props or from some kind of calculations. So you will have to update the state at componentDidMount(). Check my updated answer.